# Creating a link button and an image button in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, html, button, extjs

I want to create a link in ExtJS, but one that is made of button, so, that it contains event handlers (and I don't need to add my own event handlers.)

Also, I would like to create a button that does display a big icon with text like:
ICON
TEXT

so that the icon is not positioned on the left side, but on the top (and is larger than the default 16x16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, adding an event handler to a link is dead simple and requires about the same amount of code as handling a button click:

```
Ext.get('link-id').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopEvent(); // prevent default browser action
  // do something else
});
```

However, if you really want to use a button, then you'll simply want to add an id or custom class to it and use standard CSS to override the button's default style and make it look like a link.

Regarding customizing the button layout, Ext 3.0+ provides very flexible buttons layouts out of the box.  Have you tried to do this and are not able (if so, post some code)?  Have you looked at the [button sample page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/button/buttons.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?54602-Link-Button-or-Hyper-link